# multiple relations using same model type in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an `account` model that has the following:

```
export default Model.extend({
  primaryStaff: belongsTo('staff'),
  secondaryStaff: belongsTo('staff')
});
```

`primaryStaff` maps to the `primaryStaffId` key on the `account` model and `secondaryStaff` maps to `secondaryStaffId`. Is there a way to allow these to both point to the `staff` model?

Not having any luck. Thanks!

---

Update:

I'm using the JSON API Adapter -- here's a sample payload:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "account",
    "id": "17",
    "attributes": {
      "businessId": 1,
      "userId": 22,
      "scopes": [
        "customer",
        "customer-22"
      ],
      "keyCode": null,
      "lockboxCode": null,
      "notes": null,
      "active": false,
      "createdAt": "2017-01-31T20:13:39.465Z",
      "updatedAt": "2017-02-20T03:49:17.308Z",
    },
    "relationships": {
      "business": {
        "data": {
          "type": "business",
          "id": "1"
        }
      },
      "customer": {
        "data": {
          "type": "customer",
          "id": "22"
        }
      },
      "secondaryStaff": {
        "data": null
      },
      "primaryStaff": {
        "data": {
          "type": "staff",
          "id": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify application (or model) serializer.

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/56beeff3abbd361e18fd67ddd88a9b75)

Comment: `keyForRelationship` was precisely what I was missing. Thank you very much!

Comment: I actually can't seem to get this to work when using the JSON API adapter. See updated post above. Thanks!

Comment: Hi - I thought I had a notification that you had made some changes, but it doesn't seem to exist any longer. Did you remove it?

Comment: @jdixon04 What doesn't exist any longer?